# Magic Trick Matching 5 colors

Tags: probability

The magician has 5 cards of different colors (say red, orange, yellow, green, blue).
The spectator has 5 cards of the same colors.
They both mix up their cards.
The magician puts their cards out on the table face down.  The spectator puts a card, also face down, on top of each of the magician's cards.
When they are turned over what is the probability that all 5 pairs match.  That the spectator put a red on the red, an orange on the orange, etc.

Is it P(match remains and the card matches) X P(match remains) for each card?
which would be $(\frac{1}{5}x\frac{1}{5})x(\frac{1}{4}x\frac{1}{4})x(\frac{1}{3}x\frac{1}{3})x(\frac{1}{2}x\frac{1}{2})x(1x1) = 0.000069$

Comment: Whatever the magician does completely determines what color is where. So your problem is the same as asking what the liklihood is for the player to randomly choose the order ROYGB. Hence $1/5!$

Comment: @coffeemath - got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula calculates the probability that both the magician and the spectator have the same, but specific, order. It would be the chance, for example, of both of them putting their cards down in the specific order of  BYOGR.

But the two of them matching can be for *any* order. So, *whatever* order the spectator has, the magician 'just' needs to match that … and the probability for that is $\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1}$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Combinatory problems may frequently get a little confusing and it's important to understand, not only the correct way, but why your way gone wrong.

In the way you did, you are defining the magician cards order. But, to get the correct result asked, you need to calculate the probability of the spectator match a random order of magician's cards.

So, to match the first card there is $1$ option in $5$, so $1/5$ chance; next card is $1$ option in $4$, $1/4$ chance; doing this to all cards you will get $1/5!$, and that is your answer :)

Comment: understood. Thanks!